# Memojis in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, memoji

Every time I want to use memojis in the iOS simulator it either crashes or I get the message "unable to load memoji stickers". I tried 13.4 and 13.5 in the simulator, I also signed in with my Apple ID but nothing helps. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution for this?

Comment: No, it is still broken and I still don't why.

Comment: same issue. Any solution?

Comment: No, I still have the same problem with iOS 14.x.